# Как сделать вывод текста из БД в телеграм бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пишу бота на pyTelegramBotAPI. Хочу сделать чтобы человек нажимал на кнопку, и ему выводился текст из базы данных, как это реализовать ? Благодарю за ответ)

Comment: Добрый день. Код я Вам не дам, тк на py не пишу, но технически подскажу:. юзер кликает кнопку в чате и боту приходит запрос от этой кнопки (бот это такой же пользователь и сервер одновременно), далее бот обращается к БД средствами SQL-запроса  или какого либо иного метода, получает ответ из БД и передает его пользователю в чат. Надеюсь, чем-то, помог...

Comment: "Человек нажимает кнопку и ему выводится текст, статичный текст, заранее заданный прямо в коде, не из базы данных" - это сделано? Покажите, пожалуйста, код этого функционала прямо в вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# обработчик команды /stat
@bot.message_handler(commands=['stat'])
def stat(message):
    stat_kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    stat_kb_total = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Всего', callback_data='stat_total')
    stat_kb.add(stat_kb_total)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите', reply_markup=stat_kb)


# обработчик inline
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'stat_total':
        stat_func(call.message.chat.id, 'stat_total')  # вызов функции


# функция отправки статистики из БД
def stat_func(chat_id, where_call):
    from db_func import select_stat_ticket_type
        if where_call == 'stat_total':
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Всего:\n{}'.format(select_stat_ticket_type())


# функция выбора статистики из БД
def select_stat_ticket_type():
    ticket_type_list = ['Э', 'К', 'О', 'В', 'От']

    stat_ticket_type = ''
    for i in ticket_type_list:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        cursor = conn.execute("SELECT COUNT(row_id) FROM ticket WHERE ticket_type=?", (i,)).fetchone()
        if cursor is None:
            conn.close()
        else:
            conn.close()
            if cursor[0] == 0:
                pass
            else:
                stat_ticket_type = stat_ticket_type + i + ' - ' + str(cursor[0]) + '\n'
    return stat_ticket_type
```